# How to pass an array initializer list into a C++ templated class constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, constructor, initialization

Let's say I have following templated C++ class

```
    template<uint32_t FILTER_ORDER>
    class Filter {
    public:
    
        Filter(const float coeffs[FILTER_ORDER + 1]) {
            for (uint32_t coeff = 0; coeff < FILTER_ORDER + 1; coeff++) {
                filter_coeffs[coeff] = coeffs[coeff];
            }
        }
    
    private:
        const float filter_coeffs[FILTER_ORDER + 1];
    };
```

My intention is to pass the initializers for the member `filter_coeffs` array via the constructor of the `Filter` class i.e. I would like to achieve something like that

```
Filter<3> filter({1.0, 0.3678, 0.1353, 0.04978});
```

Can anybody tell me how to do that? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try declaring the constructor's parameter as a `std::array`, instead? Besides, the `const float coeffs[FILTER_ORDER + 1]` constructor parameter isn't really what you think it is. There is no such thing as array parameters, in C++, what you're getting here is something completely different.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thank you very much for your reaction. I haven't tried to use the std::array. Do know how to achieve the same result without std::array?

Comment: Why do you want to?  @Sam's suggestion is by far the best because the compiler will [check the length of the array passed in](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7ESWeF0PnHBvHPZR).

Comment: This requires either a `std::array`, or a `std::initializer_list`, take your pick (or some other container, but it wouldn't make much sense). There are no other options. C++ is not a language where it is possible to use any syntax, it's just the matter of figuring out how. C++ has very strict rules for everything. This syntax cannot be used with this kind of a parameter, it must be changed to a different one.

Comment: @PaulSanders please can you tell me whether there is a possibility for passing the initializer list for the member array via the constructor also in case I would like to avoid the std::array for whatever reason?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik does it mean that there is no possibility for passing the initializers for the member array via constructor in case the "ordinary" array is used?

Comment: No, and as I indicated, there is no such such thing as an array parameter to a constructor or a function, in C++. `const float coeffs[FILTER_ORDER+1]` may look like an array to you, but there it's not. This is not an array. Take my word for it. This is main reason why a braced initialization list does not work. It needs an array, and this is not an array. Asking this again will not result in a different answer, C++ just doesn't work this way.

Comment: @ProfessorJimatura Yes there is - you can declare the parameter to the constructor as being of type `std::initializer_list<float>` and call it with the same syntax as with `std::array`.  But what is your objection to `std::array`?  As I say, it is the best way to do it.